# Quotients of finite C-star algebras: are they finite?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

As I was trying to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902828/finiteness-of-a-c-algebra/4015422#4015422) question, I thought of the following: If $A$ is a unital, finite $C^*$-algebra and $I$ is an ideal in $A$, then is $A/I$ a finite $C^*$-algebra?

Recall that a unital $C^*$-algebra is called finite when the implication
$$p\sim_{M-vN}1_A\implies p=1_A$$
holds, i.e. every isometry in $A$ is a unitary. Besides the main question, I realized something: I do not know what $C^*$-algebras are finite or not. For example, I know that abelian $C^*$-algebras are stably finite, as it is (briefly) discussed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962755/abelian-c-algebras-are-stably-finite) post, and finite dimensional $C^*$-algebras are (stably) finite too, but that's all I know. So a bonus question is: what are some interesting examples of finite $C^*$-algebras besides abelian and finite dimensional ones?

Note that in the answer of the linked question I am using a particular feature of the ideal $\sum_nA_n$ in $\prod_nA_n$, something that we cannot do in the general case.

Comment: Quasi-diagonal $C^\ast$-algebras and $C^\ast$-algebras with a faithful tracial state are stably finite. The latter class includes for example the reduced $C^\ast$-algebras of countable discrete groups.

Comment: @MaoWao Nice, I will keep those examples in mind.

Comment: Btw, a proof for the first fact was discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969893/the-proof-of-every-quasidiagonal-c-algebra-is-stably-finite?rq=1

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks for the reference. Any ideas on the main question about the quotients and finiteness?

Comment: Here is a discussion about a finite but not stably finite algebra. https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-096-01/S0002-9939-1986-0813816-7/S0002-9939-1986-0813816-7.pdf

Comment: @s.harp Definitely interesting, I will check it out, but does this have any consequence related to the question about quotients?

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$
  A = \{f\in C([0, 1], \mathcal T): f(0)\in  \mathbb C\cdot 1\},
  $$
where  $\mathcal T$ is the Toeplitz algebra.  Every isometry $f$ in $A$ gives rise to a path of isometries in
$\mathcal T$ beginning with a scalar.  Observing that  all isometries in the Toeplitz algebra have finite Fredholm
index, and also that the index is continuous, we can easily show that $A$ is finite.  However
the map
$$
  f\in  A\mapsto  f(1)\in \mathcal T
  $$
is a surjection from $A$ to a non-finite algebra.

---

**EDIT**. Here is an argument to show the finiteness of $A$ which does not rely on the theory of  Fredholm operators:

**Lemma**.  Let $B$ be a unital C*-algebra.  Denote by   $\mathscr I(B)$  the set of all isometries in $B$, and by   $\mathscr U(B)$ the subset
formed by the unitary elements.  Then $\mathscr U(B)$ is clopen in $\mathscr I(B)$.

*Proof*.  It is well known that the set  $\text{GL}(B)$ formed by all invertible elements is open.  Since
$$
  \mathscr U(B) = \mathscr I(B) \cap \text{GL}(B),
  $$
it follows  that   $\mathscr U(B)$ is open in $\mathscr I(B)$.  To show that $\mathscr U(B)$ is also closed,  suppose by
contradiction that the
sequence $\{u_n\}_n$  of unitaries converges to a proper isometry $s$ (meaning that $ss^*\neq 1$).
The element
$$
  p = 1-ss^*
  $$
is then a non-trivial projection and,  clearly, $ps=0$.  We then deduce that
$$
  0 = ps = \lim_{n\to \infty }pu_n,
  $$
but this is a contradiction since $\|pu_n\|=\|p\| = 1$.  QED

This said,  suppose that $f$ is an isometry in $A$,  so we have that   $f(t)$ lies in $\mathscr I(\mathcal T)$, for all
$t$ in $[0, 1]$.

Since $f(0)$ is necessary a scalar, we have that $f(0)\in \mathscr U(\mathcal T)$, but then
$f(t)\in \mathscr U(\mathcal T)$, for every $t$ because  $[0,1]$ is connected.

This shows that $f$ is unitary and hence that
$A$ is finite.

Comment: Nice one, I am a bit unfamiliar with index theory but I am about to start studying the index map in K-theory, so I guess this answer also acts as part of my motivation! So the general idea is "take an infinite $C^*$-algebra $A$, consider its suspension, or any $C^*$-tensor product $C(X)\otimes A$ and since $C(X)\otimes A\cong C(X,A)$ this is a stably finite $C^*$-algebra, having $A$ as a quotient", right?

Comment: $C(X,A)$ is infinite if $A$ is, because $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X,A)$ (constant functions).   That is why it is important to require that $f(0)$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 3):

There is probably an obvious example laying around, but I can't think of one! Here is an overkill answer showing that quotients of finite C*-algebras need not be finite.

There is a characterization of separable exact C*-algebras as subquotients (quotient of a subalgebra) of the CAR algebra, i.e., the UHF algebra $M_{2^{\infty}}$. This algebra is finite and so is any subalgebra since the faithful trace on the CAR algebra restricts to a faithful trace on any smaller algebra. So take $B \subseteq M_{2^{\infty}}$ ($B$ unital) and $I \lhd B$ such that $B/I \simeq \mathcal{O}_2$, the Cuntz algebra generated by 2 isometries. The Cuntz algebra is (purely) infinite.

There is a nice description of finiteness in unital C*-algebras (see [Left Invertibility Implies Right Invertibility in Certain $C^*$-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567275/left-invertibility-implies-right-invertibility-in-certain-c-algebras/3567303#3567303)). Some examples are UHF algebras (like the CAR algebra), the irrational rotation algebra, the Jiang-Su algebra, etc.

References:
This was originally proved in "On subalgebras of the CAR-algebra" by Kirchberg, and later Wassermann gave a "simpler" (take with a grain of salt) proof in "Subquotients of UHF C*-algebras".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of those discriptions of finiteness, I studied those from Rordam's blue book, they are surely nice! I guess that the characterization of exact $C^*$-algebras is a deep, deep, deep, theorem?

Comment: BTW does it have to do anything with the characterization "exact if-f admits a faithful representation that has the CPAP" (another theorem of Kirchberg)?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Yep, that's the "exact" I'm talking about, although another useful characterization is that taking the minimal tensor product with the C*-algebra is an exact functor. There are some more characterizations: for example, a separable C*-algebra is exact if and only if it embeds into the Cuntz algebra $\mathcal{O}_2$ (this one is due to Kirchberg & Phillips). And yeah, a  lot of these results are quite deep.